# Server returning empty response on ajax call probably routing error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a simple search input that i want to POST data with an ajax call on click out using jquery on blur. The ajax call is the following code:

```
$(".ajax").blur(function(){



            $.ajax({

                     type: "POST",
                     url : "adminController.php",
                     data : {
                     searchInput: $(this).val()
                     },
                     dataType : "json",
                     context : $("#searchResults"),

                    success: function(data)
                         {
                            $(this).text(data);
                            alert(data);
                         },
                    error: function (xhr,textStatus,err)
                         {
                            console.log("readyState: " + xhr.readyState);
                            console.log("responseText: "+ xhr.responseText);
                            console.log("status: " + xhr.status);
                            console.log("text status: " + textStatus);
                            console.log("error: " + err);
                         }
});
        });
```

When the post call is made, i get a redirect (302 found) to my custom 404 page. However, the adminController.php is located correctly when i checked in chrome's console. If I remove the redirecting condition manually I get a 200 ok server response but with empty response. In my adminController.php I have the following code(code after the return in the constructor is not really necessary here): `

```
    class adminController
    {
        private $postData;
        private $errorMessage;
        public function __construct()
        {
        $this->postData=array();
        $this->errorMessage='';
        session_start();
        if(sessionClass::get('Username')== false || loginModel::checkAdmin()== false)
        {
            header('Location: /Costing/login');
            exit();
        }


        if(($_POST)) {
            //$this->handlePostData(); I entered the following
 simple code to make sure my json return array is not the issue for my problems
            $cars=array("Volvo","BMW","Toyota");
            return json_encode($cars);
        }

    }
    public function __destruct(){ }

    public function displayPage()
    {
        $admin = new adminModel();
        $nonAdminUsers = $admin->databaseInteract(sqlQueries::getNonAdmin());

        $adminView = new adminView();
        $adminView = $adminView->createAdminPage($nonAdminUsers);

        echo $adminView;

    }

    private function handlePostData()
    {

        foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
        {
            if(!empty($value)) {
                $sanitized_value = filter_var($value,FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS);
                $sanitized_value = filter_var($sanitized_value,FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
                $sanitized_value = filter_var($sanitized_value,FILTER_SANITIZE_MAGIC_QUOTES);
                $this->postData[$key] = $sanitized_value;

            }
            else
                $this->errorMessage.= $key.' is empty.';
        }
        if(!empty($this->postData))
        {
            $admin = new adminModel();
            foreach ($this->postData as $key => $value)
            {
                if($key == 'Seller' || $key == 'Customer' || $key == 'Product')
                {
                    $adminQuery = sqlQueries::searchOrders();
                    $tempArray['field']=$key;
                    $tempArray['value']=$value;

                    $result = $admin->databaseInteract($adminQuery,$tempArray);
                    $adminView = new adminView($result);
                }
                else if($key == 'nonAdmins')
                {
                    $adminQuery = sqlQueries::promoteToAdmin();
                    $tempArray['Username']=$value;
                    $result = $admin->databaseInteract($adminQuery,$tempArray);
                    $adminView = new adminView();
                    $adminView->displayErrors($result);


                }
                else
                {
                    $tempArray['value']=$value;
                    $adminQuery = sqlQueries::setConstants($key);
                    $result = $admin->databaseInteract($adminQuery, $tempArray);
                    $adminView = new adminView();
                    $adminView->displayErrors($result);

                }
            }
        }


    }
}`
```

what I am trying to achieve is instead of having a submit button, just post everything on blur and dump the results on the #searchResults div.
I think the problem has to do with my router class. The redirect in the first place on a post request did not seem healthy, so I will paste the code of my router and bootstrap files.

bootstrap.php:

```
    <?php

/**
 * @param $className
 * bootstrap file for autoload function and router calling
 *
 */


function my_autoloader($class) {

    if (file_exists(realpath(__DIR__). DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $class . '.php'))
    include realpath(__DIR__). DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $class . '.php';
    else if (file_exists(realpath(__DIR__). '\\Classes\\' . $class . '.php'))
    include realpath(__DIR__). '\\Classes\\' . $class . '.php';
    else if (file_exists(realpath(__DIR__). '\\Classes\\Controller\\' . $class. '.php'))
    include realpath(__DIR__). '\\Classes\\Controller\\' . $class. '.php';
    else if (file_exists(realpath(__DIR__). '\\Classes\\Model\\' . $class. '.php'))
    include realpath(__DIR__). '\\Classes\\Model\\' . $class. '.php';
    else if (file_exists(realpath(__DIR__). '\\Classes\\View\\' . $class. '.php'))
    include realpath(__DIR__). '\\Classes\\View\\' . $class. '.php';

    else
    {
       $error = new errorController('classNotFound');
    }
}

spl_autoload_register('my_autoloader');


    $routes = new router();
    $routes->add('/home', 'homeController');
    $routes->add('/login', 'loginController');
    $routes->add('/register', 'registerController');
    $routes->add('/index.php', 'homeController');
    $routes->add('/invoicing','invoiceController');
    $routes->add('/admin','adminController');
    $routes->add('/404','errorController');
    $routes->submit();
```

and router.php

class router
{

```
private $routes = array();
private $method = array();

public function __construct(){}

public function __destruct(){}
```

/**
 * Adds available routes to an array with their methods (strings, anonymous functions, etc.)
 */

```
    public function add($uri, $method = null)
        {

        $this->routes[] =trim($uri,'/');
        if ($method!= null)
            $this->method[]= $method;
        else
            throw new exception();

    }

    /**
     * Matches routes to controller actions.
     */
    public function submit()
    {
        $count=0;

        if(isset($_GET['uri'])) {
            $uri = $_GET['uri'];
        }
        else
            $uri = '/home';

        foreach( $this->routes as $key => $value)
        {

            if (preg_match("#^$value$#", $uri))
            {

                if (is_string($this->method[$key]))
                {
                    $userMethod = $this->method[$key];
                    $display = new $userMethod();
                    $display->displayPage();
                }
                else call_user_func($this->method[$key]);
            }
            else $count++;

        }

        if($count == sizeof($this->routes))
        {
            header ('Location: /Costing/404');
            exit();
        }

    }
}
```

last but not least, my .htaccess

```
ReWriteEngine On
ReWriteRule ^public/ - [L,NC]
ReWriteBase /Costing/
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?uri=$1 [QSA,L]
```

**Edit 1**: I'm using Xampp and my domain is localhost/Costing/. I tried changing the url to Costing/admin so i got rid of the redirect. But still, unless I remove the dataType = "json" I get empty response back (if i remove json i get back the full html page with the scripts, aka adminView file). Using MVC architecture

**Edit 2**: I found a way around. Seems like i was right and the routing is causing the issue. So I created an ajaxHandler.php file and placed it outside the Costing directory and edited the ajax url like this: "http:// localhost/ajaxHandler.php". I get a valid response from this file but I can't really work with a file outside the root directory. So I need to change the htaccess. Any ideas are welcome

Comment: If you have router why you send ajax request on `url : "adminController.php",`? Why not directly on _/admin_?

Comment: I tried, but I get the same result (I don't have to remove the redirection conditions though) which is 200 ok with empty response. If I remove the datatype = "json" I get back the full html page as a response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution myself, the problem was on htaccess. Basically the lines

```
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
```

Did not allow my urls to ask for files or directories, so anything ending on .php was forbidden. I had to create a folder and place my ajax handling file in there and add an exception like so:

```
ReWriteRule ^ajax/ - [L,NC]
```

Now the htaccess allows calls to this file and I can use it properly. I'm not sure this is secure though and I still have no idea why the url Costing/admin didn't work as marian correctly noted. If anyone finds out why it would be great

Answer (score 0):

Aside from your bootstrap.php I do not see any actual executing php code (i.e. index.php).

For a single server side entry point, as it looks like you are working towards, you will want all requests to end up on the entry point with the full route request intact.  From this entry point, you can then call the router which will then call the adminController class.

The order of operation then becomes:

1. Ajax request sent to /admin
2. Request is directed to the index.php
3. Index.php fires the bootstrap to load up the autoloader
4. Index.php calls the router with the incoming path
5. Router calls the actual AdminController class.

The empty response is likely because the server is only executing the adminController.php which does not appear to echo out anything (the class is never initialized in just that file).

Comment: i didn't include my index.php but the code inside is: require_once 'bootstrap.php'; The order of the operation you included is exactly the same as what was happening. I changed the url from adminController.php to /admin to send the request correctly (why i was getting the 404 error). the adminController is initialized on the router class when the /admin url is entered and the adminController->displayPage function is then called. You are right though, I changed the return json_encode($cars) to echo json_encode($cars) and still no luck. The work around is fine though

Comment: Based on that, I would suggest adding some debugging within the 'submit' method.  You might try $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] instead of $_GET, check what the values are for both. Check where you end up in the if/else in the submit.  Also, maybe add an echo 'hello world' where you are calling json_encode